# SQL Query in MS Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

**This query in the form-Data-Record Source is working fine, returning exact values that i want**

```
SELECT tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber, tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel, tblRevRelLog_Detail.Version, tblRevRelLog_Detail.JobPnType, tblRevRelLog_Detail.EdsName, tblRevRelLog_Detail.DetailerNamePerPartNumber, tblRevRelLog_Detail.DetailerCompanyPerPartNumber
FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail 
LEFT JOIN tblEventLog ON tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber = tblEventLog.PartNumber
WHERE (((tblEventLog.PartNumber) Not In 
    (SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber 
     FROM tblEventLog 
     WHERE tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper' 
         AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber =  tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber)))
ORDER BY tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber;
```

**But if i write the same query in the VBA. It is not returning anything**

```
strNewSql = "SELECT tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ID FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail LEFT JOIN tblEventLog ON tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber = tblEventLog.PartNumber"
strNewSql = strNewSql & " WHERE ((tblEventLog.PartNumber) Not In (SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber FROM tblEventLog WHERE tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper' AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber =  tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber);"
```

**Something wrong with the query?? can someone help me!**

Comment: Have you printed out the sql returned by you query and pasted it into the query design window? You can do this with `Debug.Print strNewSql`, this will print to the immediate window.

Comment: This query is displaying records now, but it is showing up all the partnumbers from the DB. when I use the same query in the Form. It is displaying right partnumbers that are related to the tracking number. But if I use the same query in VBA. That is displaying all the Partnumbers from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that your variable tempTrackingNumber is bad

Comment: It is not returning anything if I use this condition also tblEventLog.TrackingNumber = tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber

Comment: For example, is RevRelTrackingNumber really a text field?

Comment: In the first query your WHERE filter is comparing column vs column (implicit inner join) (AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber = tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber) whereas the second one you are going column against a specific single value. Check that the subquery is returning something.

Answer (score 0):

If `RevRelTrackingNumber` is numeric you don't need to enclose it in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

What's the data type of tempTrackingNumber? Your code (front-truncated) shows this:

```
...tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber = """ & tempTrackingNumber & """);"
```

This implies that it's a String, and it will be treated as such.

If it's actually numeric, you'll want this instead:

```
...tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber = " & tempTrackingNumber & ");"
```

Comment: tempTrackingNumber is alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

First, the queries are not the same. For example, your plaintext SQL has eight columns in the `SELECT` clause where the VBA version has just three.

Second, you are using the same table name, `tblEventLog`, twice in the same scope. So you will need to use at least one table correlation name. I know the tbl- prefix is a 'point of pride' in the Access world but it does make you table names longer and harder to read IMO (and prefixes are specifically outlawed by the [ISO 11179 Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_11179) for data element naming :))... so why not use table correlation names throughout?

Third, IIRC `EXISTS` performs better than `IN` for Access (ACE/Jet/whatever) and IMO is easier to understand (`DISTINCT..INNER JOIN` may perform even better but is again harder to read, IMO).

Here's a suggested re-write:

```
SELECT D1.PartNumber, D1.ChangeLevel, 
       D1.ID 
  FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail AS D1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEventLog AS E1
          ON D1.PartNumber = E1.PartNumber 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT *
                     FROM tblEventLog AS E2 
                    WHERE E2.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper' 
                          AND E2.TrackingNumber = D1.RevRelTrackingNumber
                          AND E2.PartNumber = E1.PartNumber
                  );
```

---

UPDATE: Seems I was wrong about the `EXIST` giving being better, so here's a couple more rewrite to choose from:

```
SELECT D1.PartNumber, D1.ChangeLevel, 
       D1.ID 
  FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail AS D1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEventLog AS E1
          ON D1.PartNumber = E1.PartNumber 
 WHERE E1.PartNumber NOT IN 
       (
        SELECT E2.PartNumber
          FROM tblEventLog AS E2 
         WHERE E2.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper' 
               AND E2.TrackingNumber = D1.RevRelTrackingNumber
       );
```

---

Actually, I'm struggling to get this re-writes using Access's proprietary joins. I keep getting a "Catastrophic failure" error. Here's the repro code, where am I going wrong?:

```
Sub grjieopgj()

  On Error Resume Next
  Kill Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
  With cat
    .Create _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & _
        Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
    With .ActiveConnection

      Dim Sql As String
      Sql = _
      "CREATE TABLE tblRevRelLog_Detail " & vbCr & "(" & vbCr & _
      " PartNumber VARCHAR(20), " & vbCr & " EventTypeSelected VARCHAR(20), " & vbCr & _
      " TrackingNumber VARCHAR(20), " & vbCr & " RevRelTrackingNumber VARCHAR(20), " & vbCr & _
      " ChangeLevel VARCHAR(20), ID VARCHAR(20)" & vbCr & ");"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "CREATE TABLE tblEventLog " & vbCr & "(" & vbCr & _
      " PartNumber VARCHAR(20), " & vbCr & " EventTypeSelected VARCHAR(20), " & vbCr & _
      " TrackingNumber VARCHAR(20), " & vbCr & " RevRelTrackingNumber VARCHAR(20), " & vbCr & _
      " ChangeLevel VARCHAR(20), ID VARCHAR(20)" & vbCr & ");"

      Sql = _
      "SELECT DISTINCT D1.PartNumber, D1.ChangeLevel," & _
      " " & vbCr & "       D1.ID " & vbCr & "  FROM (" & vbCr & "        tblRevRelLog_Detail" & _
      " AS D1" & vbCr & "        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEventLog" & _
      " AS E1" & vbCr & "          ON D1.PartNumber = E1.PartNumber" & vbCr & "" & _
      "       )" & vbCr & "       LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEventLog" & _
      " AS E2" & vbCr & "          ON AND E2.TrackingNumber" & _
      " <> D1.RevRelTrackingNumber" & vbCr & "           " & _
      "  AND E2.PartNumber <> E1.PartNumber" & vbCr & " WHERE" & _
      " E2.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From" & _
      " Wrapper';"

      Dim rs
      Set rs = .Execute(Sql)
      MsgBox rs.GetString
    End With
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: NOT EXISTS is no more reliable in regard to index usage on both sides than NO IN. Indeed, in my experience, it's less so.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I've now re-written using `NOT IN` but my `JOIN` re-write is getting a "Catastrophic failure" error (see VBA in answer). Any idea what this means?

Comment: I've never seen those alarming words in a Jet/ACE/Access error message. NOT IN is unreliable with using indexes on both sides, too. Both EXISTS and IN use the indexes on both sides, though. Maybe there's some way to reverse the logic at another level?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missing a closing bracket. Add ")" at the end of the query in VBA and try.